# How do I make my keypad read in the keys and display them in the box below?

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been working on this code where I have to create a functioning keypad.  It has to take 6 digits, 021814 being the code that allows you to enter and takes you to another page. If you enter more than 6 numbers, it is supposed to reset to zero, and if you put in the wrong key it is supposed to flash red and reset. I have got what I think should work, but it wont allow any numbers to be pressed.

In the beginning of my script, in lines 7, 9, 11, and 14 I get an error with the `code.innerHTML` part, saying "Value assigned to primitive will be lost". I am not sure what to do with that.

Heres what I have for my script

```
 var doSomething = function(event) {
     var id= event.target.id;
     console.log(event.target.id);

     var code = document.getElementById("code").innerHTML;
//     code = code.trim();
     console.log("[" + code + "]");
     if (code.innerHTML == "Enter Pass Code") {
         document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = event.target.id;
         code.innerHTML = id.substr(-1,1);
     } else {
         code.innerHTML = code.innerHTML + id.substr(-1,1);
     }
     if (code.innerHTML.length > 6){
         code.innerHTML = 'Enter Pass Code';
     }
 };

var backspace = function (event) {
    let id=event.target.id;
    let shown = document.getElementById("code");
    if (shown.innerHTML.length < 2) {
        if (id === 'Back') {
            shown.innerHTML = 'Enter Pass Code';
        }
    } else if (shown.innerHTML.length >= 2) {
        console.log(shown.innerHTML.length);
        shown.innerHTML =shown.innerHTML.substr(0,shown.innerHTML.length-1);
    }
};

var displayReset = function (event) {
    let id = event.target.id;
    let shown = document.getElementById("code");
    shown.innerHTML = 'Enter Padd Code';
};
var input = function(event){
    let id = event.target.id;
    let shown = document.getElementById("code");
    if(shown.innerHTML === '021814') {
        shown.innerHTML = 'Access Granted';
        window.open("http://www.shadbase.com");
    }else {
        let displayString = 'Access Denied';
        shown.innerHTML = displayString.fontcolor('red');
        setTimeout(displayReset, 1000, event);
    }
};
document.getElementById("One").addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);
document.getElementById("Two").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Three").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Four").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Five").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Six").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Seven").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Eight").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Nine").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Zero").addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
document.getElementById("Enter").addEventListener('click', input, false);
document.getElementById("Back").addEventListener('click', backspace, false);
```

And here is what I have for my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Keypad </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
          type = "text/css"
          href = "css/keypad.css" />
    <link rel="s
    stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="overall">
    <div id="accesspadtitle">
        Access Keypad
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowOne">
        <div id="One"> 1</div>
        <div id="Two"> 2</div>
        <div id="Three"> 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowTwo">
        <div id="Four"> 4</div>
        <div id="Five"> 5</div>
        <div id="Six"> 6</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowThree">
        <div id="Seven"> 7</div>
        <div id="Eight"> 8</div>
        <div id="Nine"> 9</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "numRowFour">
        <div id="Enter"> Enter </div>
        <div id="Zero"> 0 </div>
        <div id="Back"> Back </div>
    </div>
    <div id="code">Enter Pass Code</div>
</div>
<script src="javascript/keypad.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think webstorm warning tells you going to overwrite the value / reference you got with getElementById in the line before code.innerHtml, since you have 2 ways of accessing it. Also please google this error.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the following line:

```js
var code = document.getElementById("code").innerHTML;
```

to this:

```js
var code = document.getElementById("code");
```

`.innerHTML` is an attribute, so `code` becomes the content of your `#code` element note a reference to the content of your element.